# Banned words for a specific user

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

SO I have seen how to make a bot that restrics users to use specific words, but can I also do it that a specific user cant use the words?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message, user):
    if user.has_role("cheffe"):
        if any(word in message.content for word in hate_words):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("""You are not allowed to speak about animes!""")
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

`on_message` only takes in one parameter which is `"Message"` you can find the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
You can get a member object through `message.author`

Comment: That's what happens when you assume the code in the question was tested... my bad I guess p.p

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a variable (i assume list, or dict for peformance)
'hate_words' which contains forbidden words.

For example:

```py
hate_words = ["foo", "bar"]
```

Then you check for forbidden words using

```py
if any(word in message.content for word in hate_words):
   ...
```

If you want to specify the forbidden words per user,
you can change your data structure to be a dict of lists,
were the key to the dict is the `User.name` property, e.g.:

```py
hate_words_by_user = {
     "user_name_1": ["foo", "bar"],
     "user_name_2": ["bar", "baz"]
}
```

Now you can check the specific users sublist using:

```py
# user.name from the parameter that your on_message function has 
user_hate_words = hate_words_by_user[user.name]
if any(word in message.content for word in user_hate_words):
   ...
```

If you just want specific users not be able to use
the words in your single `hate_words` list (I didn't fully get which of the two you meant), you could just add a variable

```py
users_that_may_not_use_hate_words = ["user_name_1", "user_name_2"]
```

and then check like this:

```py
if user.name in users_that_may_not_use_hate_words:
    if  any(word in message.content for word in hate_words):
        ...
```